# How to test (using Jest) a function that returns a promise that contain another promise

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, jestjs, es6-promise

So, I want to test (using Jest) a function which returns a promise that contains an axios request (as another nested promise) and resolve the outer promise within `then` and `catch` blocks.

The function is similar to this:

```
   fetchFunction() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!this.valid) {
          this.value = 1;
          return resolve();
        }
        this.someModel.$get()
          .then(() => {
            this.value = 2;
            return resolve();
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.value = 3;
            return reject(e);
          });
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about unit test, you should not test both in the same test.

Ie your test for the fetchFunction() method will have a part where you mock the `this.someModel.$get()` function

You can create a mock function that return a promise like e thant :

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => return Promise.resolve('mock'))
```

More info on https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions

Comment: How would this cover the logic and side effects in each block?

Comment: The point of a unit test is to test your "unit" most probably your function, not your api, 
You can change the output of the mock funciton at each test to test every case